# Connecting to Client Data Centre using AWS VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc, site-to-site-vpn, sonicwall

I have been using AWS for the past 3 years. We have never required to connect to our client data centre using a VPN until recently. I am entirely new to the concept of VPN, however, I have figured a few things out in terms of how it works. Despite, setting up the connectivity, I am not able to fully get the connectivity established successfully.

Here are the things that I have.

Client Side Configuration:
I have the following details from the client side.

- IPSEC Gateway IP
- IP Address
- Nat IP Address
- Subnet Mask
- Allowed Ports
- Traffic Type
- Keep Alive
- IKEv1 , Phase 1 and Phase 2 Details

Steps that I have done to get the connectivity up.

1. Created a Customer Gateway(CG) with the IPSEC Gateway IP.
2. Created a Virtual Private Gateway(VPG) which is attached to VPC.
3. Created a VPN connection with VPG and selected the CG created in the previous step. Here, I have options to enter the Routing Options, Local IPv4 and Remote IPv4 Network CIDR.
4. In Routing Options, I have selected Static and entered the IP Address(2nd Line under Client Side Configuration) with /32 CIDR.
5. In Local IPv4 Network CIDR, I have entered VPC CIDR as 172.31.0.0/16
6. In Remote IPv4 Network CIDR, I have entered the NAT IP received from Client Side.
7. After all this, I have added the VPG in the Routes Table for access to VPC

---

Current Situation :
The IPSEC configuration is almost up, but the status shows as DOWN. I am trying to understand on what am I doing wrong here or missing out which will help me establish the connection successfully on both ends.

This image shows the current status:

[image: Tunnel status DOWN]

The status shows as down, however the IPSEC is UP.

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if more details are required.

Thanks in advance.